# ASP.NET MVC :get external parameters of an URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, local-storage, access-token, url-parameters

How to get the external parameters of an URL in ASP.NET MVC?

The URL might look like this:

```
https://localhost:4200/controller/callback#access_token=2723983somethingtoken&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=458623
```

The above URL is sent to the server so how can I deal with "#" in the URL?
I want to get `access_token`, `token_type` and `expires_in` from the URL and store them in localstorage or any variable to perform the further task

I tried different methods of URI like segments, PathAndQuery, query, query string

Answer (score 0):

But the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure will do everything for you. Just define an action method with parameters:

```cs
[Route("callback")]
public IActionResult Callback(string access_token, string token_type, string expires_in) {
  // Implementation
}
```

By the way, in .NET it isn't recommended to create variables such as `access_token`. `accessToken` would be better (if you change name of the parameter, don't forget to change your URL accordingly).